# ul -> a rule should not effect children ul -> a

Tags: html, css

I have the following link structure for my categories:

```
<ul>
  <li class="current-cat cat-parent">
    <a href="#">Parent-Cat</a>
    <ul class="children">
      <li class="cat-item cat-item-71">
        <a href="#">Children-Cat</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
   </li>
 </ul>
```

Now I want only the `current-cat` class to change the color of it's `a` element:

```
#outer-section .outer-div ul .current-cat a {
  color: red;
}
```

The problem is, that the children (`cat-item cat-item-71`) gets changed, too. How can I prevent that and change only the parent `a` of the `current-cat`?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the direct child selector: `.foo > .bar`

> The child combinator (>) is placed between two CSS selectors. It matches only those elements matched by the second selector that are the children of elements matched by the first.

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors)

```css
.current-cat > a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
 <ul>
  <li class="current-cat cat-parent">
    <a href="#">Parent-Cat</a>
    <ul class="children">
      <li class="cat-item cat-item-71">
        <a href="#">Children-Cat</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
   </li>
 </ul>
```

Note that I didn't use the whole selector `(#outer-section .outer-div ...)` for the example since you only provided the HTML structure from the `ul` element.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the > that will prevent the inheritance:

```
  #outer-section .outer-div ul .current-cat > a { 
       color: red; 
    }




<ul>
  <li class="current-cat cat-parent">
   <a href="#">Parent-Cat</a>
     <ul class="children">
       <li class="cat-item cat-item-71">
         <a href="#">Children-Cat</a>
       </li>
     </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```